# Has any work been done, or are there plans for work, which integrates Stack Exchange with Wikipedia?

Tags: feature-request, wikipedia

I have little in mind right now in terms of specifics, though an example might be for each to offer search results for the other in their respective local searches (perhaps in a sidebar).

I feel that the two are missioned in extremely similar manners, and users would benefit from the unified pool of knowledge. They'd probably both increase visitors by the union, as well.

---

### Update

Fleshing out my thinking in response to the first response I received below.

Their business models are different, but in a general sense, the two are here to educate.

Stack Exchange mission statement: [Make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/)

Wikipedia's mission statement: [... to empower and engage people around the world to collect and develop educational content under a free license or in the public domain, and to disseminate it effectively and globally.](https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Mission_statement)

This being the Internet, we have the option of networking resources, for the potential enrichment of all. If a Stack Exchange question is locked, it becomes more or less canonized. It is less pliable than Wikipedia at that point. Thus Stack Overflow becomes less QA at points, and more encyclopedia-like.

Both sites also benefit from increased traffic (albeit indirectly in terms of revenue for Wikipedia). Thus, links going from one to the other would increase [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization)-shared traffic.

Comment: No, the philosophies and formats of the two platforms are too different to be integrated. Though, frankly, I have no idea what you mean by "integration" here.

Comment: I mean - in chat we one-box wikipedia URLs. Is that "integration"?

Comment: @Oded By 'integrate', I mean utilize each other's APIs (if available) for the betterment of their users.

Answer (score 10):

No. There is not that I am aware of and in my opinion it shouldn't.

Your statement is wrong:

> I feel that the two are missioned in extremely similar manners

They are not. Wikipedia is an encyclopedia, Stack Exchange a practical Q/A site. Q/A and encyclopedias do not go well together. Hence, integrating or cross-posting is impossible and useless.

Both differ in their strategy and way to make money. Stack Overflow is a company, which doesn't want donations, Wikipedia a non-profit organisation that is often begging for money (I guess it's their only way of making money...).

Comment: StackExchange Mission Statement: [Make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/)

Comment: Indeed. That is not an encyclopedia...

Comment: Sorry - hit enter before I was done.

"Your statement is wrong" is inaccurate.  I do feel that way.  You may have a differing opinion, but let's [do our part to be diplomatic in our difference of opinion](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/02/28/magazine/what-google-learned-from-its-quest-to-build-the-perfect-team.html?_r=0).

I'll flesh out my question to clarify, though.

Comment: Oded (an employee) already said that the philosophies are too much apart. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Yes.  And thank you for citing a source.  I was hoping "No. There is not that I am aware of..." came from some place of knowledge.

Comment: Wikimedia being a nonprofit organization, it doesn't "make money". And despite their "begging", as you call it, they still provide free access to everyone with an Internet connection, whether they're making disparaging remarks or not.

Comment: True @najib and the 'begging' wasn't meant as a bad thing. But it is clearly the total opposite of the way SE works, with various questions about 'how to donate' getting declined.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman - Your closing comment about Wikipedia seems derisive to me as well.

Answer (score -1):

Having worked many years in knowlege management and research, it seems that while the two sites are indeed different, they are part of the knowledge gathering process.

It seems there should be some kind of feed between the two.  If wikipedia had all the answers, why then have stack exchange?  Further, if stack exchange answers questions that gives a new spin or answer on a topic, shouldn't the wikipedia article be updated?

As a long time user of the web for information, (starting 1994) I definitely see some connection between the two.  It seems that at least the sites can link to relevant articles between the two (shouldn't be too hard) in major topic areas.

Comment: +1 There seems to be some anti-Wikipedia sentiment among stack exchange the company and senior members of the community. I could be wrong, that is simply my perception as a newcomer to the site.